# can someone give me an example of springboot webservice application with wildfly webserver?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, wildfly

recently, i've stuck to create webservice with remote ejb (spring framework java application) on wildfly webserver container..can someone kindly give a simple example of how to do it...
I have read https://www.baeldung.com/spring-ejb , but something feels lost, and my understanding feels insufficient

what kind of settings need to be added and which side, more or less I don't understand it there

and what is the characteristic of spring boot that calls the bean from the remote ejb, the feature here refers to calling the line code like what shows that I have used springboot with the remote ejb